# How does Caliburn.Micro and Linq-to-SQL work together

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, linq-to-sql, caliburn.micro

I am using Caliburn.Micro and wonder if there is any convention or practice to work with a database and entities. I put all the database creation stuff in my `AppDataContext` which inherits from `DataContext`. Then I added a `container.Singleton<AppDataContext>();` in my `AppBootstrapper` and inject the `AppDataContext` into my ViewModel constructors.

This works fine but I'm not sure if it is the right way?

Another issue is how to update my `MainPage` when a new entity is inserted in the database on my `AddItemPage`. Should I always load the data from the database when I navigate back to the `MainPage`? Or should I load the MainViewModel via `IoC.Get<MainPageViewModel>();` and insert the entity manually within AddItemViewModel?

I'm sure there are a lot of options but I'm looking for the intended way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Registering the `DataContext` as singleton in the DI container and then using it in the ViewModel via constructor injection seems like a fine choice.

Using `IoC.Get` is not a good idea, it is practically the service locator anti-pattern. Another problem is, that if you register your ViewModels with `.PerRequest<>` (no reason for them to be singletons), your solution would not work, because `IoC.Get` will return a different instance of your ViewModel.

The right way to implement your use case is to use messaging (using `IEventAggregator` in Caliburn). If a user adds a new item, you send a message that will be caught by your MainViewModel (do not forget to register it for messages). Your MainViewModel can then reload all the data, or the message may contains Id of the new record and the ViewModel will just load the new record and add to the UI.

For more info about messaging in Caliburn, see http://wp.qmatteoq.com/first-steps-with-caliburn-micro-in-windows-phone-8-messaging/

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I'm looking for! One thing I am wondering is a difference between your posted link and the official [documantation](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/event-aggregator). The documentation says I need to set up `EventAggregator` as a Singleton in my Bootstrapper while the blog post just says I need to add the `IEventAggregator` to my VIewModel contructors to get injected.

Comment: no need to set it up in Windows Phone, it is done automatically (by calling container.RegisterPhoneServices(RootFrame); in the botostrapper)